# How much influence does a single participant in an opinion poll have?

Tags: polling

I consider to participate an Internet panel used by opinion poll companies. The salary is negligible; the main thing I hope to gain from participating is the opportunity to affect the outcomes, and by that, the public policy. However, since I do not know how polling works, I am not sure how much influence would I have if I participate.

For concreteness, let us assume that a certain politician orders an opinion poll in order to determine whether or not to support policy X. The poll is conducted among 1,000 citizens, who are considered a representative sample of a population of 2,000,000 citizens. The sample is constructed according to best practices in statistics. The politician is going to accept the decision of the majority of poll participants. I would like to know how much I can influence the results if I participate.

According to my simple understanding, each one of the 1000 participants represents a certain demographic section of the population, of size 2000. Therefore, if I participate and vote "yes", it counts as if all 2000 citizens in my sector voted "yes". If I do not participate, then maybe some other citizen from my sector is chosen to participate instead, and they may vote "no". As a numeric example, if 1200 citizens in my sector think "no" and 800 think "yes", and I do not participate, there is 60% chance that my sector's vote will be considered "no", but if I participate, there is 100% chance that my sector's vote will be considered "yes". So my net influence is like 60% of 2000 citizens, which is like 1200 citizens.

However, this seems a lot of influence for a single citizen. The polling company would like the poll to represent the population as accurately as possible, and therefore they probably have some measures to mitigate the influence of a single participant.

MY QUESTION: How much influence do I really have, by choosing to participate in the poll?

Comment: If the survey results are weighted to population numbers, then a single participant's impact can be huge. For example, Nielsen's household tv viewing panel can include a single guy in Denver who, based on the rarity of his cross-classified demographic, can be given a huge weight...in the tens of thousands. So, he tunes into some late night tv program when real viewership is sparse and, on a weighted basis, counts as tens of thousands of viewers, thereby influencing the price of advertising and media which is rated in CPM. cost/thousand viewers. The same relationship holds for opinion surveys